# Is it possible to view map of contacts from front end of the website in Joomla?

Tags: contacts, joomla

I want to display all my contacts/specific group map in front end of Joomla website. is this possible ?

Comment: Please add more details about what exactly you want to do, and what you've already tried based on the documentation you've read.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

Have a look at "How to create member listings/directories/maps" on my post on profiles: https://aghstrategies.com/content/civicrm-profiles-beyond-contributions-registrations-part-1